# Chromium webdriver error when running as root

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, celery, selenium-chromedriver

On Ubuntu16, Selenium fails when running from a Python/Celery task or from python with sudo. Running script manually runs without problem.

Sample error:

```
$ sudo /var/www/my_proj/env/bin/python
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/var/www/my_proj/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 75, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/var/www/my_proj/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 154, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/var/www/my_proj/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 243, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/var/www/my_proj/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/var/www/my_proj/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35 (0),platform=Linux 4.4.0-116-generic x86_64)

>>>
```

Here is how it runs perfectly without sudo:

```
$ /var/www/my_proj/env/bin/python
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
>>>
```

Chromium/Xvfb were installed as:

```
sudo apt install xvfb -y
sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver -y
```

Comment: By the way, running non-administrative tasks with root's privileges is not a healthy habit.

Comment: Activate logging for chromedriver https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/logging and for Chromium itself https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging to see why Cromium crashes. That might be connected to environment differences (user data directory, env vars etc.)

Answer (score 3):

Activating logs, as suggested by comments, helped me to find/fix the error above when running with `sudo`. To run as superuser I need the `--no-sandbox` argument. as below:

```
$ /var/www/my_proj/env/bin/python
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>>
>>> chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
>>> chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
>>>
>>> driver = webdriver.Chrome(
...   '/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver',
...   service_args=["--verbose", "--log-path=/tmp/CHROMIUM_LOG"],
...   options=chrome_options)
>>>
```

But when called by a `Celery` task, my Python code was still raising an error trying to open Chromium. I had `Xvfb` running as a service managed by `supervisorctl` and set `DISPLAY` on `/etc/environment` but still, just when called by a Celery task it wasn't working. My solution was to use `pyvirtualdisplay` somewhat like below on my Celery task:

```
$ pip install pyvirtualdisplay
$ /var/www/my_proj/env/bin/python
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>>
>>> display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
>>> display.start()
>>>
>>> driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
>>>
>>> driver.quit()
>>> display.stop()
```